# FormData is not working in IE11?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, form-data, vue-resource

I using VueJS and have using a plug-in vue-resource to make a request, but I don't know why when I trying to use FormData to send to server then it not working in IE11?

Here is code:

```
HTML:

<head>
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
</head>

JS: 
    let data = new FormData();

    data.append('title', StringUtil.nullToString(title));
    data.append('description', StringUtil.nullToString(description));

    Vue.http.post('/api/v1/media-files/' + file.id, data).then(response => response.data);
```

Can you help me? Thank you!

Comment: what error are you getting? (in Developer Tools Console)

Comment: I don't see anything :(

Comment: surprising since IE11 can't handle arrow functions

Comment: I think that isn't problem Jaromanda X, because it was build to ES5 syntax by grunt :), I think may be I should try install window again :)

Comment: Well, yes, that would help :p

Comment: Thank your feedback, Jaromanda X :)